# What could possibly be causing this NPE in onCreate?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, oncreate

I am getting an NPE in onCreate of the following file (MySubActivity):

```
public class MySubActivity extends MySuperActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myTextView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.myString));
    }
}
```

MySuperActivity:

```
public class MySuperActivity extends Activity {
    protected TextView myTextView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

        myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextViewid);
    }
}
```

The strange thing is that I have never seen this crash while testing the app. The page works fine when I test it. However I got a crash report from Google notifying me of the crash. I cannot reproduce it, and I have no idea under what scenario this crash could happen. Seeing as how it works for me, the resource ids and string names etc. must be correct.

The only thing that came across my mind was that maybe the user had their phone set to a different language, so it couldn't properly pull the resources. However, there are default resources for all of them, and I tested changing the language of my emulator and it didn't crash. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe use `myTextView.setText(R.string.myString);` instead?

Comment: @petey `R.string.myString` is an id of the string if I'm correct

Comment: @petey thanks for advice. I will try that. Is there any scenario you know of that could cause `myTextView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.myString));` to crash and `myTextView.setText(R.string.myString);` to work?

Comment: Not really.  Do you know the device and os version/api-level?  that might help understand whats going on.

Comment: @petey I know the device was a SCH-R760X which appears to be a Samsung Galaxy S2 running 2.3. Unless the phone was rooted.

Answer (score -1):

Set your view in another method, like this:

```
public class MySubActivity extends MySuperActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void setView(){
        myTextView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.myString));
    }
}
```

### Edit: Don't call setView() in MySuperActivity

```
public class MySuperActivity extends Activity {
    protected TextView myTextView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

        myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextViewid);
        // Or, you can do this in a method called getView() if you like
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not true, because OP called `super.onCreate()`. You even get a compile error if you do not call `super.onCreate()`.

Comment: @LawrenceChoy I don't get you. I called super.onCreate() in both activities. Could you provide further explanation? Thanks in advance

Comment: What I meant is your statement `The onCreate() in mySubActivity overrides the onCreate() in its parent class, so findViewById() will not be called.` is not true. Because OP called `super.onCreate()` in `MySubActivity`, the `onCreate()` of `MySuperActivity` will be called, thus `findViewById()` will also be called.

Comment: Lawrence is correct. `findViewById()` is called. Like I said, this crash does not happen in any test case I have run.

Comment: I've tested and found you're right, thanks for pointing it out!